# how can I javascript decodeURI in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, urlencode, encodeuricomponent

I have a javascript which sends some specific information to a PHP api . Before to send it performs encodeURI . How can I "decode" it in PHP ? I understand that urldecode/urlencode is different that javascript encode/decodeURI so what can I use ?

Comment: would using the javascript escape() and unescape() function work for you?

Comment: If the PHP is not getting the information via querystring don't use `encodeURI`, simple as that. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Use `encodeURIComponent` in Javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp and `urldecode` in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 6):

Unless you've encoded it multiple times (e.g. by explicitly calling the encode method AND inserting the value into a form field which is then submitted) you don't need to do anything - it is transparently converted back to its original form when the request is parsed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rawurldecode` function in php, but this function is not UTF-8, then your have to convert to UTF-8 with `utf8_decode` like this

```
echo utf8_decode(rawurldecode('Educa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20Multim%C3%ADdia'));
```