# unable to export html table using jquery and php $_GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, excel

my downloaded table only prints headers and does not display any content.
  iam following the tutorial from here:http://webslesson.blogspot.in/2016/02/export-mysql-data-to-excel-in-php-php-tutorial.html

THE FOLLOWING PLUGINS i have tried which fails to render my huge data
   1.clarketm(merges rows)
   2.(tried but unable to render huge dat)https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin

my HTML DOM IS (**index.php**)

```
<div id="allTables">
    <table border="2" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <th width="30%">Name</th>
                    <th width="20%">Activity on Code Project (%)</th>
                    <th width="10%">Activity on C# Corner (%)</th>
                    <th width="10%">Activity on Asp Forum (%)</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sibeesh</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                    <td>98</td>
                    <td>80</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ajay</td>
                    <td>90</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>50</td>
                </tr>
                    </table>
</div>
<p id="exportexcel">EXport to Excel</p>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#exportexcel').click(function(){
          var excel_data = $('#allTables').html();
          console.log(excel_data);
          var page = "excel.php?data="+excel_data;
          console.log(page);
          window.location = page; // here iam sending data to excel.php through get method
 });
</script>
```

my **excel.php** file is

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
  header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.rand().'.xls');
  echo $_GET["data"];
?>
```

--please help me what iam doing wrong thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure the GET string really wants HTML in it and in particular the equals signs in your data will look like valid GET string separators. I think you might want to send you data via POST. Perhaps you should look at jQuery and $jquery.post().

Comment: @Paul i have seen the tutorial,which was working for them http://webslesson.blogspot.in/2016/02/export-mysql-data-to-excel-in-php-php-tutorial.html

Comment: you might need to url encode the excel_data

Comment: what is in console.log(excel_data);  ?

Comment: @Abhijit,it is something like this excel.php?data=    <table border="2" width="100%"> ..... whole data

Comment: @furrie how can i do that please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity on C# Corner (%) - "#" in this line is causing the problem. encoding this will resolve the issue in above code.

But its better to use POST as suggested.

Comment: ,how come you are so accurate,i have removed Activity on C# Corner (%)  and is working man

Answer (score 0):

If you pass html code via get then you must encode it else you can use post method.
 following code would be useful to you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var htmlString= document.getElementById(allTables).innerHTML;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "excel.php",
    dataType:'html',// ***add this option!***
        data: {html:htmlString},
        success: function (data) {
            // this is executed when ajax call finished well
             alert('file has been saved');
             location.reload();
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            // executed if something went wrong during call
            if (xhr.status > 0) alert("Error: " + status); // status 0 - when load is interrupted
        }
    });
    }

</script>
```

**Your excel.php file should be**

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
  header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.rand().'.xls');
  echo $_POST["html"];
?>
```

> and if you want to use $_GET then you should refer
>   [how can I javascript decodeURI in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146501/how-can-i-javascript-decodeuri-in-php)
>   to encode and decode uri in javascript to php