# How to encode and decode hindi content in javascript and php

Tags: php, ajax

I want to send a `Hindi` message from my custom php page. For this I have used a `ajax` request.

How to `encode` it in JavaScript before sending in ajax and `decode` it in `php function`?

**EDIT**

Here is my code :

```
...
var message = ''; // here I am getting content from form field dynamically
var ajaxBlockUrl = '/my.php?action=custom&mobile=999999999&message='+message;
Ajax.Request(ajaxBlockUrl, 
{
    parameters: {isAjax: 'true', form_key: FORM_KEY},
    onSuccess: function(response) 
    {
        //
    }
});
...
```

Comment: post your code lets we try

Comment: Please refer this [javascript decodeuri in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146501/how-can-i-javascript-decodeuri-in-php)

Comment: Hello @Mack4Hack, I tried `encodeURIComponent` and `urldecode` but it is not working for me.

Comment: Hello @LifeTimeProgrammer, please check my edited question.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari What happens when you use `urldecode`?

Comment: i test this code its working , `var world = "A string with symbols / characters that have special meaning?";
var uri = 'http://example.com/foo?hello=' + encodeURIComponent(world);
alert(uri);` @VinayaMaheshwari

Comment: Hi, yes this code working with `English` message but I want to send message in `hindi`, How to do that?

Comment: hi @VinayaMaheshwari are you try with `<html encoding="UTF-8" charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: How to use `<html encoding="UTF-8" charset="UTF-8">` ? My page only added content on page, header and footer are comes from differnet template.